# PHP case insensitive count of words common between 2 strings

Tags: php, string-comparison

I'm trying to take 2 pieces of text in php like this...

```
"A cat jumped over the hat"

"The mad hatter jumped over his cat"
```

And get results like this...

```
the
cat
jumped
over
```

(i.e. the common words between the strings, where hat is NOT included because it's part of another word in the second string)

I've found a bunch of examples to help count occurrences of 1 string within another, but that would end up giving me the "hatter" problem so I'm guessing I need to tokenize both strings into word-lists and do one-to-one compares somehow.

Struggling to visualise an efficient way to achieve that though so appreciate any thoughts at all on what the correct approach is.  Thanks!

Comment: [str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) is a very useful function, especially with 1 or 2 as the format value; and you can [walk each array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) forcing [lowercase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and then [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: but my understanding is that I can just use that to do something like str_word_count(string,1) to get the array of words for each string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, I'd use `explode` to separate each string into words, then create an array for each string where the keys are the words, and the values all just `true`. Then, you can take one of the arrays, loop through its keys, and check whether they're present in the other array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner using

- [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)
- [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)
- [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

---

```
<?php

$str1 = "A cat jumped over the hat";

$str2 = "The mad hatter jumped over his cat";

print_r(array_intersect(array_map("strtolower", explode(' ',$str1)), array_map("strtolower", explode(' ',$str2))));
```

Results in this output:

```html
Array
(
    [1] => cat
    [2] => jumped
    [3] => over
    [4] => the
)
```